# What is the p.value for each individual test in my prop.test function?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, p-value

What is the p-value for each individual test in my prop.test function? (See code below).

When doing multiple testing (k = 10 000 tests in this case), I want to find the alpha for each individual test in prop.test, since it obviously is not 0.05. The function prop.test must be adjusting the p-value somehow.

Upon reading on the internet and in R (typing prop.test in the console), I did not find an answer to what the p-value is and how to obtain it. I realize that typing prop.test in the console can help but I tried it and could not understand the prop.test-code well enough to understand what the alpha (for individual test) is. Hence, I would appreciate if someone could explain how I can obtain this number for alpha (for individual tests).

Thanks a lot in advance,
/Pedram

```
k <- 10000

pH0 <- 1:k
pH1 <- 1:k
nA <- 4000
nB <- 4000
p0 <- 0.01
p1 <- 2*p0

a = 0.05
pD = a

for(i in 1:k)
{
      x1 <- rbinom(1,nA,p0)
      x2 <- rbinom(1,nB,p0)
      y <- rbinom(1,nA,p1)

      pH0[i] <- prop.test(c(x1,x2),c(nA,nB))$p.value < pD
      pH1[i] <-prop.test(c(x1,y),c(nA,nA))$p.value < pD 
}
print(paste("FDR =",sum(pH0)/sum(pH0+pH1)))
print(paste("True positives =",sum(pH1)/k))
print(paste("FWER =",(1-((1-pD)^k)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The alpha level is defaulted at 0.5 unless you specify `conf.level` as something other than `0.95`:

```
prop.test(x, n, p = NULL,
          alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
          conf.level = 0.95, correct = TRUE)
```

`conf.level` is the same as `1-alpha`. The above code block is taken from the RStudio help menu.

Comment: Thank you @JakeFeuerman. I have actually seen that and tried using "conf.level = 0.95" in my prop.test in the code, it had no change on the output (rate of type I error) for me.  Problem persists, any idea as to what it can be?

Comment: Specify a different `conf.level` if you want it to be something other than 0.95. It is defaulted to 0.95.